# Eigen headers not found (include pb)

Tags: qt-creator, eigen

Just trying to use Eigen template library with QtCreator IDE on Windows 8.1 system, I copied the entire Eigen subdirectory from the downloaded package and added an INCLUDEPATH line in my project's .PRO file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = testEigen
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += d:/Qt-apps/Eigen
SOURCES += main.cpp
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
```

My main.cpp reads:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MatrixXd m(2,2);
    m(0,0) = 3;
    m(1,0) = 2.5;
    m(0,1) = -1;
    m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

And compilation error is :

```
D:\Qt-apps\testEigen\main.cpp:3: erreur : Eigen/Dense: No such file or
directory
#include <Eigen/Dense>
                       ^
```

I saw Icarus' post with somewhat similar problem and answer by πάντα ῥεῖ. That seems petty thing but being not at all familiar with external reference nitty-griddy stuff, I am still stuck...

Thank for any help!

Comment: Did you copy the contents of the `Eigen` subdirectory into `d:/Qt-apps/Eigen`, or did you copy the `Eigen` subdirectory? (i.e., is there a directory `d:/Qt-apps/Eigen/Eigen`?)

Comment: I copied the Eigen subdirectory into d:/Qt-apps/Eigen , with all content including a Dense file and the src subdirectory

Comment: So there actually exists a file `d:/Qt-apps/Eigen/Eigen/Dense` on your harddrive?

Comment: No, the file complete path is: d:/Qt-apps/Eigen/Dense. Isn't it what it should be?

Comment: I may have misunderstood installation guideline. Should I copy the whole decompressed donwloaded package and rename it "Eigen"? (current package name is "eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb")

Answer (score 1):

You apparently put the contents of the Eigen sub-folder into `d:/Qt-apps/Eigen`, therefore the compiler can't find a `Eigen/Dense` file inside the include-path (that would need to be located at `d:/Qt-apps/Eigen/Eigen/Dense`.

The quickest solution is to write

```
INCLUDEPATH += d:/Qt-apps
```

but I recommend putting the entire content of Eigen (i.e., the whole archive, or repository contents) into a directory like `d:/Qt-apps/eigen3` and write

```
INCLUDEPATH += d:/Qt-apps/eigen3
```

into your `.PRO`-file.

To clarify: Inside the compressed package should be (amongst others) a folder called `Eigen` -- that is what the `Eigen` in `#include <Eigen/Dense>` refers to. This `Eigen` folder must be a sub-folder of some entry in the include-path.

Comment: I followed your recommendation and it compiles w/o error.
Everything clear now, much thanks to you chtz!